# How to call the gloabaly declare values and pass to all function in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask login page
Two(so many) href links will be there

- test1
- test2

from this href link redirect to some submit boxes, almost all variables are same

Below are the two methods which i call, all the variables are same except `dirName2` and `return`. How to write this variable only one time

```
    @app.route('/test1',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def test1():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            fname = request.form.get('fname')
            uid = request.form.get('uid')
            dirName = os.path.join('static', fname + uid)
            if not os.path.exists(dirName):
                os.mkdir(dirName)
                print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
                dirName2 = os.path.join(dirName,'test1')
                if not os.path.exists(dirName2):
                    os.mkdir(dirName2)
                    print  ("Directory " , dirName2 ,  "created")
                else:
                    print  ("Directory " , dirName2 ,  " already exists")
            else:
                print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
        return render_template('test1.html')

    @app.route('/test2',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def test2():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            fname = request.form.get('fname')
            uid = request.form.get('uid')
            dirName = os.path.join('static', fname + uid)
            if not os.path.exists(dirName):
                os.mkdir(dirName)
                print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
                dirName2 = os.path.join(dirName,'test2')
                if not os.path.exists(dirName2):
                    os.mkdir(dirName2)
                    print  ("Directory " , dirName2 ,  "created")
                else:
                    print  ("Directory " , dirName2 ,  " already exists")
            else:
                print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
         return render_template('test2.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be doing like this.

```
def do_test(request, test_name):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.form.get('fname')
        uid = request.form.get('uid')
        dirName = os.path.join('static', fname + uid)
        if not os.path.exists(dirName):
            os.mkdir(dirName)
            print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
            dirName2 = os.path.join(dirName, test_name)
            if not os.path.exists(dirName2):
                os.mkdir(dirName2)
                print  ("Directory " , dirName2 ,  "created")
            else:
                print  ("Directory " , dirName2 ,  " already exists")
        else:
            print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
    return render_template(f'{test_name}.html')

@app.route('/test1',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test1():
    return do_test(request, 'test1')

@app.route('/test2',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test2():        
    return do_test(request, 'test2')
```